# Inserting An Image from UIImagepicker into UICollectionViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

Hey just wondering if its possible to Select a specific image from the photolibrary and implement into a Collection View

so the idea is to have an image the user can select from the photolibrary then fill the selected image into a cell within the collection view i would also like to be able to save the image so if the user deletes the photo from the library it remains within the application ( was thinking i could save the image within firebase or NSUserdefaults?

Answer (score 0):

A controller demonstrating how to select photos to display in a collection view [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/keicoder/9224472).

If you're only going to be saving a single image, then putting it at a known path like demonstrated here would work: [How to save a remote image with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285808/how-to-save-a-remote-image-with-swift)

If you're trying to manage multiple images, it's probably a good idea to look into Core Data and have it manage the images' `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` NSData for you. (Be sure to set "Store in External Record File" for the image data record if you do this!)